# AWS for iOS: Cannot find type 'AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest' in scope

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

It looks like a basic problem, but it's more complicated that it seems.

In my iOS project, I imported some AWS libraries:

- `Amplify`, in order to call webservices (API Gateway), using SPM
- `AWSS3` and `AWSMobileClient`, in order to get a presigned URL, so I can manually download a file from a S3 bucket (and no, I don't want to use `Amplify.Storage.downloadData` since I have specific needs), using Cocoapods

When I want to get a presigned URL for my custom S3 client, here is what I do:

```
let awsS3GetPreSignedURLRequest: AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest = AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest()
awsS3GetPreSignedURLRequest.httpMethod = AWSHTTPMethod.GET
awsS3GetPreSignedURLRequest.key = key
awsS3GetPreSignedURLRequest.bucket = bucketName
awsS3GetPreSignedURLRequest.expires = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(900))
AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder.default().getPreSignedURL(awsS3GetPreSignedURLRequest).continueWith { [self] task in
   // ...
}
```

It has always worked fine, until I added the `Amplify` library using SPM.

Now, for some reason, I get the following errors at compile time:

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find type 'AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest' in scope
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Cannot find 'AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder' in scope
```

Of course, I checked that I have: `import AWSS3`

I cleaned every possible cache, rerun a `pod install`, but it doesn't want to compile.

**UPDATE:** Here is a [test project](https://github.com/mregnauld/AWSAmplifyDemo/tree/master) for you to try. The problem appears as soon as I add the `Amplify` library using SPM.

How can I fix that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try to create a Mock App to reproduce de problem. Only the necessary that we can download and run in our machines. Maybe we can help this way. Your problem is so specific that only someone with exact needs of yours can identify a previous problem that had an occur to them. As you can see, just by the error message is impossible to identify.

Comment: @AllanGarcia I just updated my post with a link to a test project where you can see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, the problem came from the fact that, when I added the `Amplify` framework using SPM, I checked `AWSS3StoragePlugin`.

Not checking that plugin solved the problem.

Comment: Great. See... the mock app definitely helped. Congrats!